# Are there any differences between URLs with and without "www" and "http://"

Tags: url, http, no-www

Are there any differences among these addresses?

- `www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `example.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`http://www.example.com` and `www.example.com` would refer to the same thing.  Modern browsers assume that the protocol is `http://`.   Some browsers are even starting to hide the implicit `http://` when showing URLs in the URL bar.

`www.example.com` and `example.com` can be very different.  It is possible to run two different sites at those addresses with completely different content.  That wouldn't be good for users and most websites take one of three approaches to making those addresses work as expected:

- Redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`
- Redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com`
- Serve the same content at both `example.com` and `www.example.com`

Comment: Which one is more seo-friendly?

Comment: None is more SEO friendly, you can choose which one you prefer (between `www.example.com` or `example.com`).

Comment: Just to be clear, the first two options (redirection) are both better for SEO than the last one. But there is no difference SEO-wise between example and www.example.

Comment: Placing a canonical url meta tag on the webpage would by a plus here and help search engine to get then indexed with single copy.

Comment: Make sure that the redirection is a 301

Comment: If the naked domain is used (e.g. `example.com`) then there is no way to set up sub-domains without cookies. With `www` it is possible to set up a sub-domain(s) that does not have cookies for the serving of static assets. Cookies require data transfer and therefore slow load times; fast load times positively impact SEO and user experience...that said, I have never done this myself and the difference in performance and SEO is often almost negligible.